# Querying eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have the following set for relations in my eloquent models/db:

`Student` has many `PhdReport`

`PhdReport` has one `Link`

I need to get `Student`s where the (single) most recent `PhdReport` (by the attribute `date_to`) is more than 6 months and the `Link` connected to the `PhdReport` has a `status` of 'complete'.

I am trying to do this using eloquent relationships and I'm pretty new to the concept of querying relationships so I would like to know if there's a better approach to the one I'm taking.

Here's the relevant code so far:

**PhdReport.php**

```
public function link()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Link::class);
}
```

**Student.php**

```
public function phdReport()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\PhdReport::class);
}

public function latestPhdReport()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\PhdReport::class)->latest('date_to');
}

/* this doesn't work! */    
public function lastPhdReportSixMonthsAgo()
{
    $sixMonthsAgo = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth(6);

    return $this->whereHas('latestPhdReport', function ($query) use ($sixMonthsAgo) {
        $query->where('date_to', '<=', $sixMonthsAgo);
    });
}
```

This is my best shot at it so far but I am unsure if the first `whereHas` applies to the second `whereHas` also?

```
$sixMonthsAgo = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth(6);

$students = $this->student
    ->whereHas('phdReport.link', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'complete');
    })
    ->whereHas('latestPhdReport', function ($query) use ($sixMonthsAgo) {
        $query->where('date_to', '<=', $sixMonthsAgo);
    })
    ->get();
```

If I run:

```
$students = $this->student
    ->has('lastPhdReportSixMonthsAgo')
    ->get();
```

I get:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1994:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getRelated()
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: This will do http://softonsofa.com/querying-relations-in-laravel-get-models-where-latest-related-is/

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk thanks for the link. I have a working solution now but it definitely needs some fine tuning. I will post up an answer once I'm happy with it. Thanks again for your help - really appreciate it.

Comment: Cool. Share your code once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution, I haven't had time to refactor yet but I'm sure it can be improved by doing only a query and no filter. Will edit when I get time but thought I'd put it up as it might help someone else. Much credit to @JarekTkaczyk

```
$monthsAgo = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth($months);

// Query 1: students with a completed report
$studentsWithCompletedLink = $studentsWithCompletedLink
    ->whereHas('phdReport.link', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'complete');
    })
    ->get();

if ($months != 0) {
    // filter through to get students where the report date_to is more than $months months ago
    $studentsWithReport = $studentsWithCompletedLink->filter(function ($student) use ($monthsAgo) {
        return $student->latestReport->date_to <= $monthsAgo;
    });
}
```

**Student.php**

```
public function latestPhdReport()
{
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\PhdReport::class)->latest('date_to');
}
```